# Application integration issue

Tags: rest, soap-client

We have implemented Application on REST, but our client has SOAP function, how can I integrate application on my clients (SOAP)module.
Can you help me on this issue?

Thanks in Advance
Giridhar

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use a SOAP proxy on your RESTful service and avoid adding any complexity on the client side. 
Check out the Sample# 152 from this: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB451/Proxy+Service+Samples